# NoSQL data modeling: different profile types

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

Say I have a user who can belong to multiple roles within a group. It is modeled like this (from third party library).

```
{
  _id: '1',
  roles: {
    'repo1': ['contributor'],
    'repo2': ['contributor', 'moderator', 'reviewer']
  }
}
```

For each role type, there is a different profile type. For example, a `reviewer` might have a schema like so:

```
{
  approved: [{
    pullRequest: '5678',
    message: 'Now can manage 3D integration',
    when: ISODate()
  }],
  denied: [{
    pullRequest: '1234',
    reason: 'Failed tests',
    when: ISODate()
  }]
}
```

which might be different than a `contributor`'s profile. Users can still have a profile in every group for every role they are in.

In NoSQL, how do you manage multiple types of user profiles? What is the most correct type of schema and relationship for this application?

Answer (score 0):

In your example, I assume a reviewer is approving and denying pullRequests. This is information you would not want to store on a user's document, but instead offset to a new collection you would probably call PullRequests. Each document in the PullRequests collection would represent a single PullRequest and you would store information regarding that particular PullRequest on that document, including if it was approved/denied and subsequently who approved/denied it and for what reason. Storing the role on the user document is for validation purposes so that you can check to see if someone has the required permissions; logging information regarding their activity is best left to a separate Collection. It's a clear separation of concerns and this model relationship will be easier to maintain.

Feel free to ask any follow ups.

Comment: makes sense, but say that the `moderator` profile contains a list of these pull requests that he has approved or denied, and a `contributor` profile contains a list of the pull requests that he submitted. How would you differentiate these two profiles?

Comment: I would instead store that information on each individual PullRequest document. If you need to look up all the PullRequests a moderator approved you would use something like `PullRequests.find({approvedBy: user._id})`. In MongoDB it's very important to recognize parent/child relationships. A user **is** standalone. A user **has a** role. A pull request has it's status set **by** a user.